# Display flex crashing after page resfresh

Tags: css, flexbox, font-awesome

I am trying to use flexbox with font awesome icon and its pseudo element. I'm getting the desired look only on VSC live server until I refresh the page, then everything crashes. Tried to add `flex-wrap: wrap` or wrap into another div but the problem still appears:

```css
.option {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  outline: 5px solid white;
}

.fa-solid {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.fa-solid::after {
  content: "Meditate";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="option"><i class="fa-solid fa-brain"></i></div>
  <div class="option"></div>
  <div class="option"></div>
</div>
```

Desired result:
[image: This is how I want it to look, and it works till refresh]

After refresh:
[image: This is what happens after refresh]

Comment: Hi! could you please upload section html

Comment: We don't really see anything with the code you posted. Can you add some content and explain how it doesn't look like you expect it to?

Comment: Can you please recreate this on some online tool like https://codepen.io/ and share the link here

Comment: Snippet does not function or reproduce problem. Please fix snippet

Comment: _"until I refresh the page, then everything crashes"_ - that sounds much more like a caching-related issue, than anything that would have to do with the specific CSS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.